# How to do grouping of list of dictionary in Python?

Tags: python

I am newbie in Python. I have a list of dictionary which look like as below

```
[
    {
        'key1': 'value1',
        'key2': [
            {
                'id': 1,
                'name': 'name1'
            },
            {
                'id': 2,
                'name': 'name2'
            },
            {
                'id': 3,
                'name': 'name3'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        'key1': 'value1',
        'key2': [
            {
                'id': 1,
                'name': 'name1'
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        'key1': 'value1',
        'key2': [
            {
                'id': 1,
                'name': 'name1'
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to convert this list into lists of list on the basic of common key2-id, The resultant list will look like

```
[
    [
        {
            'key1': 'value1',
            'key2': [
                {'id': 2, 'name': 'name2'},
                {'id': 3, 'name': 'name3'}]}
    ],
    [
        {
            'key1': 'value1',
            'key2': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'name1'}]
        },
        {
            'key1': 'value1',
            'key2': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'name1'}]
        },
        {
            'key1': 'value1',
            'key2': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'name1'}]}
    ]
]
```

I have tried to accomplish this using `gropby` from itertool as below:

```
from itertools import groupby
def _group_by_key2_ids(results):
    groupby_iterator = groupby(
        results,
        lambda x: [item.get('id') for item in x.get('key2')]
    )
    return [list(x) for _, x in groupby_iterator]
```

It doesn't give the result that I want. Its output look like

```
[
    [
        {
            'key1': 'value1',
            'key2': [
                {'id': 1, 'name': 'name1'},
                {'id': 2, 'name': 'name2'},
                {'id': 3, 'name': 'name3'}]}
    ],
    [
        {
            'key1': 'value1',
            'key2': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'name1'}]
        },
        {
            'key1': 'value1',
            'key2': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'name1'}]}]
]
```

Please let me know, how we can do this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: just wanted to say good job for including input + desired output + code you tried + current output. exactly how questions are supposed to be asked.

Comment: I quite don't understand how it should work, in your desired output the **id 1** is not there, just **2 and 3**, why? Sorry if I get it wrong..

Comment: Notice: the elements within `groupby`'s result groups will always be elements from the original iterable. your iterable is a list of `dict`s,  so the elements (wherever they may be grouped) would be those same `dict`s.

so, basically, no groupby key function you provide will cause it to split the content of the inner list.

any answer will need to first transform the list of dicts by some logic, then group, and then transform back again.

Comment: @EsdrasXavier, **id 1** is there. Its part of second list in group result

Comment: I see. Thanks, i didn't got it

Comment: But why **2 and 3** steyed together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flatten the data and apply `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
data = [{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'name1'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'name2'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'name3'}]}, {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'name1'}]}, {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'name1'}]}]
new_d = sorted([(i, a['key1']) for a in data for i in a['key2']], key=lambda x:x[0]['id'])
result = [[{'key1':d, 'key2':c} for c, d in b] for a, b in itertools.groupby(new_d, key=lambda x:x[0]['id'])]
```

---

```
import json
print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
  [
    {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "name1"
        }
    },
    {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "name1"
        }
    },
    {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "name1"
        }
    }
 ],
 [
    {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "name2"
        }
     }
  ],
  [
    {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "name3"
        }
     }
   ]
]
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why exactly ids 2 and 3 stayed together.

here's a version that groups by individual inner dicts (those with `id`),

I'm not sure if that's helpful or by which logic you group the dicts later on, if you help me wrap my head around it maybe I can help get you desired output:

```py
from itertools import groupby
from pprint import pprint

original = [
    {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'name1'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'name2'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'name3'}]},
    {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'name1'}, ]},
    {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'name1'}, ]}
]

keyfunc = lambda x: x['key2'][0]['id']

flattened_and_sorted_by_key2 = sorted([{'key1': d['key1'], 'key2':[inner_d]} for d in original for inner_d in d['key2']], key=keyfunc)

grouped_flattened = [list(x) for _, x in groupby(flattened_and_sorted_by_key2, key=keyfunc)]

pprint(grouped_flattened, indent=2)
```

this outputs 3 groups, one for each value of `id`:

```
[ [ {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'name1'}]},
    {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'name1'}]},
    {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'name1'}]}],
  [{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': [{'id': 2, 'name': 'name2'}]}],
  [{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': [{'id': 3, 'name': 'name3'}]}]]
```